Managing Excel Data with .NET C# Interop - Handling File Access Errors and Long Formulas 255 characters
I'm seeking guidance on manipulating Excel data using .NET C# Interop. Currently, I'm using Interop and it's working fine for setting values, performing calculations, and reading output. However, I encounter occasional errors when accessing the file with more than 10 users simultaneously.
Could someone advise me on the best approach or library to achieve this using .NET C#? Any code examples or resources demonstrating how to accomplish these tasks would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have attempted to utilize EPPlus 7, but encountered a restriction wherein formulas exceeding 255 characters trigger an error, such as: 'The length of a DataValidation formula cannot exceed 255 characters.


I encounter occasional errors when accessing the file with more than 10 users simultaneously: Excel isn't a database. You should encounter issues when more than one user is accessing the file simultaneously.

Yeah - I would say that you prob need a database - a database can cope with more users  - more complex queries for the data / calculations etc.
